# how to access variable value , from a different screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Q1:** how can i get the a certain variable value that is being used in a different screen?
i am trying to change the background color of appbar and button by reading a variable that is being used on another screen ?

Explanation:
I am fairly new to flutter and experimenting with different things, i have about 5 to six flutter screens and on the 5th screen there is a dropdown list which has 3 values see the code :

```
                 Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      child: ListTile(title: Text("select one",style: TextStyle(fontfamily: "Ubuntu",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black),),
                        subtitle: DropdownButton(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          items: [
                            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("option1"),value: "option1",),
                            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("option2"), value: "option2"),
                            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("option3"), value: "option3"),
                          ],
```

i want to get these values and use them on other screens based on the selected option
for example : if option 1 is selected then do this
if option 2 is selected then do that

**Q2:** i intend to use simple if statements , once i can get the values from the screen5 , is using if statement the right way to of doing it ?

**EDIT 1:** i did what Nitesh suggested :
this is my code in the 5th screen:

```
print(Value.getString());
```

but i am getting the error that error: The method 'getString' isn't defined for the type 'Value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new class that will store the value for you.

Something like this:

```
      class Value {
        static String value;
        static void setString(String newValue) {
          value = newValue;
        }

        static String getString() {
          return value;
        }
      }
```

So, when your dropdown is clicked you can call the

> Value.setString(value)

to store the value.

And on the 5th screen you can call the

> Value.getString()

to get the stored value and use it.

Note: There are a lot of different ways to do it. But this is the simplest, according to me.

Comment: i got the error >>>>>The method 'getString' isn't defined for the type 'Value'.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typing mistake, i had named the function getValue rather than getString. I have changed it, you can try it now.

Comment: yeah noticed that , i am fairly new to programming to i didnt noticed it at first , thanks , works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to learn about State Management.

Here is a solution based on [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) and [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks).

[image]

1. Define a Provider (Here, a `StateProvider`)

```
final optionProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => options.first);
```

2. Watch its `state` inside the `build` method

```
final _currentOption = useProvider(optionProvider).state;
```

3. Modify its state

```
onChanged: (value) => context.read(optionProvider).state = value,
```

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _currentOption = useProvider(optionProvider).state;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyApp'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SettingsPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('CURRENT: $_currentOption')),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _currentOption = useProvider(optionProvider).state;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Settings')),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
          value: _currentOption,
          items: options
              .map((option) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(option),
                    value: option,
                  ))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (value) => context.read(optionProvider).state = value,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final optionProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => options.first);

final options = List.generate(5, (index) => 'Option $index').toList();
```

### Other State Management Systems

You have also other State Management packages available, as described here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options