# how to access variable and its data from different screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Is there a way to access variables from different screen in flutter? What I am trying to do is i've been trying to perform a basic calculation but it won't let me since one of the variable that I am trying to calculate is defined from the other screen. Here is my code:

```
double amount = 0;
Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    balance += amount;  // here is where I get an error since balance is not define from this screen it was define from the other screen. My plan is to add the current balance from the amount that came from the user and update that output base on this result. 
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Continue",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
```

Here is my other code from the different screen:

```
double balance = 0;
child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              "Current Balance: $balance",  // This is where I want to display the output base on the calculations I have done on the other screen. 
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I think that on the main screen you also need to call ```setState()``` to display the new ```balance``` value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access variable value , from a different screen in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196971/how-to-access-variable-value-from-a-different-screen-in-flutter)

Comment: The accepted answer is not the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

To display the `balance` value on the main screen you have to refresh the stateful widget. If you widget it not stateful , make it so. Add a key to it so that you can control it from the other screen and also make its state non private.

From `class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>`

to `class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>` .

At at the top of your code a Global key like this: `GlobalKey<MyStatefulWidgetState> widgetKey = GlobalKey();`

Then when you declare your page on your main.dart file , declare it like `MyStatefulWidget(key: widgetKey)`.

Now , you create a variable inside the state to display on the screen and give it the value of balance.
 `double _balance = balance;`

Create a method that refreshes the value.

```
void refreshBalance(){
 setState((){
  _balance = balance;
 });
}
```

and

```
child: Text("Current Balance: $_balance",
       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
```

On the other page on the `onPressed` property add this to your code after the `setState()` call:
`widgetKey.currentState!.refreshBalance();` (thats how you call the function from within a state)

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for flexibility. All you need is a proper setup of the provide package and you're good to go.

Comment: hello, thank you for this will try to read this package and see if I can apply this with my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73436918/19485352

you can put your variables in empty file